# Grails Spring Security Active Directory login failed when runnable jar in docker container

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I'm using a grails 4 runnable jar with spring Security. 
Authentication is mapped to an Active Directory. 
It works fine in dev mode and when run with `java -jar` on `openjdk 11.0.2 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)`

The same in a docker container (on the same host) fails with the "wrong password" error (really not obvious in our beloved Active Directory): `javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580 ]`

Dockerfile is

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest
EXPOSE 8080

RUN mkdir /opt/app
COPY build/libs/*.jar /opt/app/app.jar

CMD ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/opt/app/app.jar"]
```

I'm guessing something is different somewhere in the system properties but which one...

Answer (score 0):

I guess adding "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" just solved my problem.